# How to retain escape characters like &quot; or &lt or &gt while parsing XML and writing them back as new XML file

Tags: java, xml-parsing

Following is the code used and below element contents are changed which is not desired by replacing the escape character,

```
  <SelectionFilter>event.ProductType == &quot;CM_Media_Server&quot; and event.ProductVer == &quot;3.0.0.6&quot; and event.ProductPatch == &quot;0&quot;</SelectionFilter>

  <SelectionFilter>event.ProductType == "CM_Media_Server" and          event.ProductVer == "3.0.0.6" and event.ProductPatch == "0"</SelectionFilter>
```

Below is the code used,

```
         Document xmlDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder().parse(SourceXMLFile);
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression exprPre = xPath
                .compile("/SPIRITConfiguration/@Version");
        NodeList list = (NodeList) exprPre.evaluate(xmlDocument,
                XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            list.item(i).setTextContent(ModelVersion.getValue());
        }

        // write the content back into new renamed xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xmlDocument);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(DestxmlFile));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Kindly help me on this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On your `DocumentBuilderFactory`, you can call the `setExpandEntityReferences` method to turn the setting off:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
Document xmlDocument = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(SourceXMLFile);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Steve K, but looks like this did not help.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is do a search/replace on the `&` to replace with `&amp;` before you parse, but this is not an ideal solution in most cases as it might cause other issues.